# How to send a POST request from a Firefox extension?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

I would like to send a POST request to a web server from a firefox extension.

I have found this example to send POST requests;
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Creating_Sandboxed_HTTP_Connections#HTTP_notifications

but I can't get it to work.

I currently have code like this;

```
    var ioService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/io-service;1"]
                              .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIIOService);
var uri = ioService.newURI("http://www.google.com", null, null);
gChannel = ioService.newChannelFromURI(uri);

postData = "a=1&b=2&c=3";

var inputStream = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/io/string-input-stream;1"]
    .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIStringInputStream);

inputStream.setData(postData, postData.length);

var uploadChannel = gChannel.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIUploadChannel);

uploadChannel.setUploadStream(inputStream, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", -1);
uploadChannel.requestMethod = "POST";
uploadChannel.open();
```

but I get an error about "cant modify properties of a WrappedNative"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using XMLHttpRequest object.
There is no same origin policy in extension development

Comment: My code is in a module that I am importing using Components.utils.import and it doesn't seem to be able to access and create new XMLHttpRequest objects.

Comment: @user329931 `Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"].createInstance();`

Answer (score 3):

I use the following code to test if a URL exists:

```
if( typeof XMLHttpRequest == "undefined" ){
        var req = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/xmlextras/xmlhttprequest;1"]
                            .createInstance();
}
else{
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
try{
    req.open( "GET", "https://" + request.URI.host + request.URI.path );
    var timeOutID = httpNowhere._getWindow().setTimeout(function () { 
        req.abort();
        Services.prompt.alert(null,"Info","nok "+ "https://" + request.URI.host 
                                                + request.URI.path );
    }, (redirectTimer));

    req.onreadystatechange = function (e) {

            if (req.readyState==4){
                Services.prompt.alert(null,"Info","ok "+ "https://" + request.URI.host 
                                                       + request.URI.path );
                req.abort();
            }
        }
    req.send( null );

} catch (err) {
Services.prompt.alert(null,"Info",err);
}
```

Comment: Real nice to see another fellow fiefox addon stackoverflow contributor. Especially nice to see updates to the old topics as the new way of doing things is much improved. Please keep it up intika!

Answer (score 1):

requestMethod is an attribute on [nsIHttpChannel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIHttpChannel) so you will need to call QueryInterface on gChannel before you can set it.